# How do I sum a column with cells that have multiple values separated by a comma?

Tags: google-sheets

This might get a little messy, but bear with me.

Say Column C has 10 cells. Each cell has several values separated by commas;C2 may have "1, 10, 9, 80", C3 may have "2, 25, 90, 5", etc. I want to sum the entire column somewhere.

Currently, I can sum a single cell with commas with the following formula; `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUM(SPLIT(C1,","))))`, but I would like to sum all of the cells in that row.

Is this possible?

Here is a copy with columns C-F needing to be separately summed:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-iCEzZenqWzauIF6_brRlQgHmGmc8eAObXKhJwI8k5U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

Just apply the formula to the range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUM(SPLIT(C1:C3,","))))
```

Comment: This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,C1:C10),", "))
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This works fine.